# 3-bit finite state machine in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fsm, gray-code

```
entity project4 is
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           x : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           myoutputs : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0));
end project4;

architecture Behavioral of project4 is
type state_type is (s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7);
signal state: state_type;

begin
process1: process(clk,reset)
begin
     if (reset ='0') THEN state <= s0;
      myoutputs <= "000";
ELSE IF (clk'EVENT AND clk='1') THEN
    case state is
     when s0 =>
               if (x="00") THEN
                  state <= s1;
                  myoutputs <= "001";
                  ELSE IF (x="01") THEN
                  state <= s7;
                  myoutputs <= "111";
                  ELSE IF (x="10") THEN
                  state <= s2;
                  myoutputs <= "010";
                  ELSE
                  state <=s4;
                  myoutputs <= "100";
      END IF;

      when s1 =>
                if (x="00") THEN
                    state <= s2;
                    myoutputs <="010";
                    ELSE IF (x ="01") THEN
                    state <= s0;
                    myoutputs <= "000";
                    ELSE IF (x ="10") THEN
                    state <=s0;
                    myoutputs <= "000";
                    ELSE
                    state <= s0;
                    myoutputs <="000";
        END IF;

        when s2 =>
                  if (x="00") THEN
                     state <= s3;
                     myoutputs <="011";
                     ELSE IF (x="01") THEN
                     state <= s1;
                     myoutputs <="001";
                     ELSE IF (x="10") THEN
                     state <=s5;
                     myoutputs <="110";
                     ELSE
                     state <=s3;
                     myoutputs <="011";
        END IF;

        when s3 =>
                  if (x="00") THEN
                     state <=s4;
                     myoutputs <="100";
                     ELSE IF (x="01") THEN
                     state <= s2;
                     myoutputs <="010";
                     ELSE IF (x="10") THEN
                     state <= s1;
                     myoutputs <= "001";
                     ELSE
                     state <=s1;
                     myoutputs <= "001";
        END IF;

      when s4 =>
                if (x="00") THEN
                state <=s5;
                myoutputs <="101";
                     ELSE IF (x="01") THEN
                     state <= s3;
                     myoutputs <="011";
                     ELSE IF (x="10") THEN
                     state <= s5;
                     myoutputs <="101";
                     ELSE
                     state <= s5;
                     myoutputs <="101";
        END IF;

        when s5 =>
                  if (x="00") THEN
                     state <= s6;
                     myoutputs <="110";
                     ELSE IF (x="01") THEN
                     state <= s4;
                     myoutputs <= "100";
                     ELSE IF (x="10") THEN
                     state <= s7;
                     myoutputs <= "111";
                     ELSE
                     state <= s7;
                     myoutputs <= "111";
        END IF;

        when s6 =>
                  if (x="00") THEN
                     state <= s7;
                     myoutputs <= "111";
                     ELSE IF (x="01") THEN
                     state <= s5;
                     myoutputs <="101";
                     ELSE IF (x="10") THEN
                     state <= s4;
                     myoutputs <="100";
                     ELSE
                     state <= s2;
                     myoutputs <="010";
        END IF;

        when s7 =>
                  if (x="00") THEN
                     state <= s0;
                     myoutputs <="000";
                     ELSE IF (x="01") THEN
                     state <= s6;
                     myoutputs <="110";
                     ELSE IF (x="10") THEN
                     state <= s3;
                     myoutputs <="011";
                     ELSE
                     state <= s6;
                     myoutputs <= "110";
        END IF;
        end case;
        end process process1;

process2: process(state)
begin
      case state is
        when s0 => myoutputs <= "000";
        when s1 => myoutputs <= "001";
        when s2 => myoutputs <= "010";
        when s3 => myoutputs <= "011";
        when s4 => myoutputs <= "100";
        when s5 => myoutputs <= "101";
        when s6 => myoutputs <= "110";
        when s7 => myoutputs <= "111";
        end case;
end process process2;

end Behavioral;
```

[Here's entire code](http://ideone.com/cYRXed).

Can someone tell me what causes the error? I'm just not getting it.
(Syntax error near "when".)

Comment: Code in link "Here's entire code" is actually incomplete.

Comment: At what line do you get the syntax error?

Comment: Your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the complete code should be present (including the context clause) allowing replication of the problem. Your linked code may disappear overtime lessening the value of your question to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use elsif not else if**

Constructing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from your linked code by adding a context clause:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity project4 is
    port ( 
        clk:        in  std_logic;
        reset:      in  std_logic;
        x:          in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
        myoutputs:  out std_logic_vector (2 downto 0)
    );
end entity project4;

architecture behavioral of project4 is
    type state_type is (s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7);
    signal state: state_type;
begin
process1: 
    process (clk, reset)
    begin
    if reset ='0' then 
        state <= s0;
        myoutputs <= "000";
    else if clk'event and clk='1' then
        case state is
            when s0 =>
                if x = "00" then
                    state <= s1;
                    myoutputs <= "001";
                else if x = "01" then
                    state <= s7;
                    myoutputs <= "111";
                else if  x = "10" then
                    state <= s2;
                    myoutputs <= "010";
                else
                    state <= s4;
                    myoutputs <= "100";
                end if;
            when s1 =>
                if  x = "00" then
                    state <= s2;
                    myoutputs <= "010";
                else if  
                    x = "01" then
                    state <= s0;
                    myoutputs <= "000";
                else if  x = "10" then
                    state <= s0;
                    myoutputs <= "000";
                else
                    state <= s0;
                    myoutputs <= "000";
                end if;

            when s2 =>
                if  x = "00" then
                     state <= s3;
                     myoutputs <= "011";
                else if  x = "01" then
                     state <= s1;
                     myoutputs <= "001";
                else if  x = "10" then
                     state <= s5;
                     myoutputs <= "110";
                else
                     state <= s3;
                     myoutputs <= "011";
        end if;

            when s3 =>
                if  x = "00" then
                     state <= s4;
                     myoutputs <= "100";
                else if  x = "01" then
                     state <= s2;
                     myoutputs <= "010";
                else if  x = "10" then
                     state <= s1;
                     myoutputs <= "001";
                else
                     state <= s1;
                     myoutputs <= "001";
                 end if;

            when s4 =>
                if  x = "00" then
                    state <= s5;
                    myoutputs <= "101";
                else if  x = "01" then
                     state <= s3;
                     myoutputs <= "011";
                else if  x = "10" then
                     state <= s5;
                     myoutputs <= "101";
                 else
                     state <= s5;
                     myoutputs <= "101";
                 end if;

            when s5 =>
                if  x = "00" then
                    state <= s6;
                    myoutputs <= "110";
                else if  x = "01" then
                    state <= s4;
                    myoutputs <= "100";
                else if  x = "10" then
                    state <= s7;
                    myoutputs <= "111";
                else
                    state <= s7;
                    myoutputs <= "111";
                end if;

            when s6 =>
                if  x = "00" then
                     state <= s7;
                     myoutputs <= "111";
                else if  x = "01" then
                    state <= s5;
                    myoutputs <= "101";
                else if  x = "10" then
                    state <= s4;
                    myoutputs <= "100";
                else
                    state <= s2;
                    myoutputs <= "010";
                end if;

            when s7 =>
                if  x = "00" then
                    state <= s0;
                    myoutputs <= "000";
                else if  x = "01" then
                    state <= s6;
                    myoutputs <= "110";
                else if  x = "10" then
                    state <= s3;
                    myoutputs <= "011";
                else
                    state <= s6;
                    myoutputs <= "110";
                end if;
            end case;

    end process process1;

process2: 
    process(state)
    begin
        case state is
            when s0 => myoutputs <= "000";
            when s1 => myoutputs <= "001";
            when s2 => myoutputs <= "010";
            when s3 => myoutputs <= "011";
            when s4 => myoutputs <= "100";
            when s5 => myoutputs <= "101";
            when s6 => myoutputs <= "110";
            when s7 => myoutputs <= "111";
        end case;
    end process process2;
end behavioral;
```

And using a couple of different VHDL tools:

> ghdl -a project4.vhdl
>   project4.vhdl:39:13: 'end' is expected instead of 'when'
>   ghdl: compilation error

and

> ```
> nvc -a project4.vhdl  
> ** Error: unexpected when while parsing if statement, expecting end  
>   File project4.vhdl, Line 39  
>                 when s1 =>  
>                 ^^^^  
> ** Error: unexpected when while parsing if statement, expecting end  
>   File project4.vhdl, Line 55  
>                 when s2 =>  
>                 ^^^^  
> ** Error: unexpected when while parsing if statement, expecting end  
>   File project4.vhdl, Line 70  
>                 when s3 =>  
>                 ^^^^  
> >...
> ```

explains what the problem is.  You're using `else if` instead of `elsif` which results in the wrong number of end statements (`end if;`).

Fixing those 17 instances of else if and we find you left out the end if for the first if statement:

> ghdl -a project4.vhdl
>   project4.vhdl:146:9: 'if' is expected instead of 'process'
>   ghdl: compilation error

Adding that right before the end process:

```
        end if; -- added
    end process process1;
```

and your design analyzes.

Whether or not your code is functional is left to you.

(Okay, there's another problem you drive `myoutputs` from two processes which will cause `X`s, you should remove the second process. Each process that assigns a signal has a driver for that signal, and std_logic is a resolved type, meaning the two drivers values will presented to a resolution function, which for package std_logic_1164 will result in `X`s for conflicting values on the two drivers.)

So there were 18 syntax errors, plus the code isn't functional, myoutputs having driver conflicts.

I removed superfluous parentheses and added spaces and indentation for readability.

So adding a small testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity project4_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of project4_tb is
    signal clk:        std_logic := '0';
    signal reset:      std_logic;
    signal x:          std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
    signal myoutputs:  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
begin
DUT: 
    entity work.project4
        port map (
            clk => clk,
            reset => reset,
            x => x,
            myoutputs => myoutputs
        );

CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
        if now > 360 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

STIMULI:
    process
    begin
        wait for 6 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        for i in 0 to 3 loop
            x <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,x'length));
            wait for 80 ns;
        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

We can see what your design does in simulation:

[image: project4_tb.png]